# c# Threading a nested loop function with two separate jobs per execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to improve the speed of my program without changing the algorithm.

Currently I use this implementation of DFT:

```
public double[] dft(double[] data) {
        int n = data.Length;
        int m = n;// I use m = n / 2d;
        float[] real = new float[n];
        float[] imag = new float[n];
        double[] result = new double[m];
        float pi_div = (float)(2.0 * Math.PI / n);
        for (int w = 0; w < m; w++) {
            float a = w * pi_div;
            for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
                real[w] += (float)(data[t] * Math.Cos(a * t)); //thinking of threading this
                imag[w] += (float)(data[t] * Math.Sin(a * t)); //and this
            }
            result[w] = (float)(Math.Sqrt(real[w] * real[w] + imag[w] * imag[w]) / n);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It is rather slow but it has one spot where I can see improvements can be made.
The internal parts of the functions are two separate tasks. The real and imaginary summations can be done separately but should always join to calculate the result.

Any ideas? I tried a few implementations I saw on the web but they all crashed and I have very little threading experience.

Comment: How long is `double[] data`?

Comment: A user selects the length. It can be anywhere from 1000 - 1million samples.

Comment: [Parallel Aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx) may help in this case.

Comment: If you're willing to give up precision, consider hiding sin/cos behind a lookup table and/or leveraging a sqrt approximation. real/imag arrays can be replaced by local scalar variables. Also make all the floats into doubles to avoid the casts.

Comment: Good info, thanks. The floats are an intended cast since an api I use for display asks for a float array.
 I will take a look at the solutions suggested tonight.

Comment: The main trouble OP has is the complexity of O(n^2). Even with some lookups he is going to get 1,000,000,000,000 iterations. That gonna be slow.

Comment: Yeah. I was instructed to try to improve the hardware's usage of the algorithm and not the algorithm itself.

Comment: this looks ideal for GPU...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a CPU bound algorithm that can be parallelized you can easily transform you single threaded implementation into a multi-threaded using the [`Parallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

In your case you have two nested loops but the number of iterations of the outer loop is much larger than the number of CPU cores you can execute on so it is only necessary to parallelize the outer loop to get all cores spinning:

```
public double[] ParallelDft(double[] data) {
  int n = data.Length;
  int m = n;// I use m = n / 2d;
  float[] real = new float[n];
  float[] imag = new float[n];
  double[] result = new double[m];
  float pi_div = (float)(2.0 * Math.PI / n);
  Parallel.For(0, m,
    w => {
      float a = w * pi_div;
      for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
        real[w] += (float)(data[t] * Math.Cos(a * t)); //thinking of threading this
        imag[w] += (float)(data[t] * Math.Sin(a * t)); //and this
      }
      result[w] = (float)(Math.Sqrt(real[w] * real[w] + imag[w] * imag[w]) / n);
    }
  );
  return result;
}
```

I have taken your code and replaced the outer for loop with [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx). On my computer with eight hyper-threaded cores I get a sevenfold increase in execution speed.

Another way to increase the execution speed is to employ the SIMD instruction set on the CPU. The [`System.Numerics.Vectors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858218(v=vs.111).aspx) library and the [Yeppp!](http://www.yeppp.info/) library allows you to call SIMD instructions from managed code but it will require some work on your behalf to implement the algorithm using these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `Task` for inner `For`, and each task will save result in a thread safe dictionary (`ConcurrentDictionary`).

I think following code be useful:

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<int, double> result = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, double>();
        public  void dft(double[] data)
        {
            int n = data.Length;
            int m = n;// I use m = n / 2d;
            float pi_div = (float)(2.0 * Math.PI / n);
            for (int w = 0; w < m; w++)
            {
                var w1 = w;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    float a = w1*pi_div;
                    float real = 0;
                    float imag=0;
                    for (int t = 0; t < n; t++)
                    {
                        real += (float)(data[t] * Math.Cos(a * t));
                        imag += (float)(data[t] * Math.Sin(a * t)); 
                    }
                    result.TryAdd(w1, (float) (Math.Sqrt(real*real + imag*imag)/n));
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Each thread should have it's own collection and only at the end the results should be aggregated, instead of a shared ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: Results in collection are independent so it's not importance order of each iteration in first For. Finally we can sum  results.

Comment: What I mean is, that it's very inefficient to use concurrent dictionary for this matter.